# Require file that is stored on internet

Tags: ruby

I want to include files from internet into my local script. Something like this:

```
require 'www.example.com/script.rb'
```

How do I do that properly?

And if possible I would rather upload my own script onto www.example.com/ and run it via `ruby http://wwww.example.com/script.rb` from terminal.

Any suggestions?